# Can't delete second or third selected index

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have 3 list boxes and when I have three things selected and click the delete button it deleted the text in the first list box but then gives a exception saying a value of -1 is not valid for index. This is my current code:

```cs
lstBoxOne.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex);
lstBoxTwo.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex);
lstBoxThree.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex);
```

[image]

wondered if theirs a way to delete all three selected text with a click of a button

Edit: I have now put image of full expection
[Full exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9ZzP.png)

Edit 2: Here is an example with full code

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void LstBoxOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var deleteD = lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex;
            lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex = deleteD;
            lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex = deleteD;
    }


    private void BtnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBoxOne.Items.Add(this.txtOne.Text);
        lstBoxTwo.Items.Add(this.txtTwo.Text);
        lstBoxThree.Items.Add(this.txtThree.Text);
        this.txtOne.Focus();
        this.txtOne.Clear();
        this.txtTwo.Focus();
        this.txtTwo.Clear();
        this.txtThree.Focus();
        this.txtThree.Clear();
    }

    private void BtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lstBoxOne.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex);
        lstBoxTwo.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex);
        lstBoxThree.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex);


    }
private void LstBoxTwo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var deleteD = lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex;
            lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex = deleteD;
            lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex = deleteD;
        }

        private void LstBoxThree_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var deleteD = lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex;
            lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex = deleteD;
            lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex = deleteD;
        } 
    }


    }
    }
```

Comment: because you deleted the item you then try get the referncefor, the selectedindex will change to -1 if it was only 1.... you need to remember the number, or, start at the end and do lisbox3, then 2, then 1

Comment: @BugFinder what do you mean start at the end? Like put the code like this? Sorry if i'm asking simple questions ' lstBoxThree.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex) lstBoxTwo.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex); lstBoxOne.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex);'

Comment: yes, as I said.. listbox3 then 2 then 1

Comment: @BugFinder That doesn't work, I'm still getting the same error. Would be grateful if you could help me a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted works as expected provided that you have selected an item in each of the three `ListBox`es. Which means the exception is occurring in code you haven't showed us. If I were a betting man, I'd say you probably have a `SelectedIndexChanged` event that's firing and not checking that the `SelectedIndex` is greater than `-1`, but you'll need to show us all of your code and preferably the entire exception  to be sure.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson Hi, I have now put the full exception, that is all my code for the delete function I am trying to create, do you want more?

Comment: The code to remove items from the boxes works as expected, provided you have an item selected so the problem must be in some other part of the form - most likely an event handler. Do you have any event handlers on those list boxes? Post the code of the entire form, or if that's too much create a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post that.

Comment: @JoshuaRobinson I have made a example and its causing the same problem, I have added the code to the original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event on `lstBoxOne`.

Inside of `BtnDelete_Click`, when you remove the selected item from `lstBoxOne` this causes `lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex` to change. This causes `LstBoxOne_SelectedIndexChanged` to fire **BEFORE** the item is removed from `lstBoxTwo` and `lstBoxThree`. When `LstBoxOne_SelectedIndexChanged` finishes and returns to `BtnDelete_Click`, `lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex` and `lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex` are both `-1` and the `Exception` is occurring due to passing `-1` to `RemoveAt`.

```csharp
private void LstBoxOne_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var deleteD = lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex;
   lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex = deleteD;
   lstBoxThree.SelecteIndex = deleteD;
}

private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   lstBoxOne.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex); //This line triggers the SelectedIndexChanged event on lstBoxOne.
   // By the time we get back to this function, lstBoxTwo and lstBoxThree have had 
   // their SelectedIndex set to -1. That is what is causing the exception to occur.

   lstBoxTwo.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex); //Ooops! lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex was set to -1 in LstBoxOne_SelectedIndexChanged.
}
```

A simple way to correct this would be to store the selected index of each `ListBox` before trying to remove any items. Also, protect yourself by checking for `-1`.

```
private void DeleteBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int lstBoxOneIdx = lstBoxOne.SelectedIndex;
   int lstBoxTwoIdx = lstBoxTwo.SelectedIndex;
   int lstBoxthreeIdx = lstBoxThree.SelectedIndex;

   if (lstBoxOneIdx > -1)
   {
      lstBoxOne.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxOneIdx);
   }

   if (lstBoxTwoIdx > -1)
   {
      lstBoxTwo.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxTwoIdx);
   }

   if (lstBoxThreeIdx > -1)
   {
      lstBoxThree.Items.RemoveAt(lstBoxThreeIdx);
   }
}
```